# How to get the value of a specific XML tag using StaX

Tags: java, xml, tags, stax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use StaX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061125/how-to-use-stax)

Hey guys so I have an XML file and I want Java to spit out the value of a specific tag. For example here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <dennis>
        <hair>brown</hair>
        <pants>blue</pants>
        <gender>male</gender>
    </dennis>
```

So let's say I want Java to spit out the value of "gender" is there code I could use like

```
XMLStreamReader.goToTag("gender");
System.out.println(XMLStreamReader.getLocalName());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("input.xml");
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
xsr.nextTag();
while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("gender")) {
    xsr.nextTag();
}
```

**XPath APIs**

You could also use the `javax.xml.xpath` APIs:

```
package forum12062255;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XPathDemo {

    private static final String XML = "<dennis><hair>brown</hair><pants>blue</pants><gender>male</gender></dennis>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xpf.newXPath();

        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(XML));
        String result = (String) xPath.evaluate("//gender", inputSource, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guitarroka.

When I started my studying of XML parsing with Java I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html).

Using STaX you will need something like this (won't post full code list):

```
 if (event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("gender"))
```

If you insist on getting one specific tag value, you should look through DOM parser, it builds a tree from XML document, so you will be able to access element "gender" (examples of DOM are listed in [link below](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)).
Good